# Git: pull --rebase without fetching

Tags: git

When I go to a branch I usually use `git pull --rebase` which will do a fetch from remote and then will rebase my commits on to the fetched branch. Which is fine. I like it very much because it keeps the history simple and linear.

There are situations where I know I don't want to fetch, because I just did it one minute ago. And me making a bad assumption of this has a very little impact. My fetch is very slow (approximately 20 seconds) because of the repository size. So I want to avoid it.

Let's call the branch in question `MyBranch`

Thing that works but I consider it being error prone:

```
$ git rebase orign/MyBranch
```

I think it is error prone because I have to remember and type in (with the help of auto completion) the name of the current branch. Compared to my intent this is just an opportunity to make mistakes.

I could write a shell script that determines the name of the current branch and then issues this command properly. But I wouldn't do it if there were a simpler solution.

So it would be ideal if I could have a `git pull --rebase --no-fetch` functionality without making helper scripts.

Comment: I thought that _was_ what `git rebase` did by default?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Without any arguments?

Comment: Yes, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: @jonrsharpe Your answer was the best. I would like to award you with a like and some bonus. Please post an answer if you want it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the typing/error prone aspect, maybe just use [the shortcut](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtupstreamemegemmasterupstreamememuem) for current branch's remote counterpart :

```
git rebase @{u}
```

If your currently checked out `MyBranch` branch is set to track `origin/MyBranch`, this will be equivalent to typing `git rebase origin/MyBranch`.

---

Even faster, set an alias : (here `ru` for "Rebase on Upstream", but choose any name you prefer)

```
git config alias.ru 'rebase @{u}'

# then
git ru
```

Comment: As @jonrsharpe said `git rebase` without any argument also does what I need. But this answer is still valid.

Comment: I was not aware of this default behaviour for `rebase`, I admit. Duly noted.

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the 1st comment (by @jonrsharpe) just do `git rebase`.

Comment: #1: I don't want to merge. I want to rebase. It is essential #2: I also want to avoid giving the name of the current branch. As I explained it in detail it is just an opportunity to make mistakes.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that this is wrong if you’re working on a separate branch which is stored in the remote but isn’t the primary/main/master branch of the remote.

Comment: Might be, not sure, it worked for me. However, I edited the answer.